# start array in C at higher index

Tags: c, arrays

I have this array with numbers that contains the binary coordinates for a 8x8 LED display.

Now i would like to have the same but for characters. This is one pretty simple because the index is the character of the number itself.

So index 1 will display 1, index 2 will display 2 and so on ...

I would like to have a array that starts at index number 65 and higher.

The idea is to pass a character array and get the equivalent ASCII number with atoi for each character and then loop throught the array to pick the right data.

How could I start at Index 65?

I thought it would be okay to substract 65 each time I get a value from atoi but it feels wrong somehow.

This way i could say That A is equal 0, B is equal 1 and so on.

```
#define ZERO {0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}
#define ONE {0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,1}
#define TWO {0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,1,1,1}
#define THREE {1,1,1,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,1}
#define FOUR {0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,1},{0,1,0,1},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1}
#define FIVE {1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0},{1,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}
#define SIX {0,0,1,1},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}
#define SEVEN {1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0}
#define EIGHT {0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}
#define NINE {0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0}

byte numbers[10][6][4]={
  {ZERO},
  {ONE},
  {TWO},
  {THREE},
  {FOUR},
  {FIVE},
  {SIX},
  {SEVEN},
  {EIGHT},
  {NINE},
};
```

Comment: Just subtract before you index into the array.

Comment: Is there any reason for those preprocessor defines?

Comment: Shouldn't there be no `,` after `{NINE}`?

Comment: @JohnBupit: That's explicitly allowed for easier automatic generation of code.

Comment: @Deduplicator the defines are just for the readability. What is wrong with them?

Comment: Unless you need the defined token sequence multiple times, they don't add anything. Better add e.g. a comment. Also, you should generally avoid the preprocessor because it just does dumb text replacements, without any regard for semantics.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot change the starting array index in C. It will always be zero.

If manually subtracting in each access is too much trouble, you could make a macro or function to perform the operation automatically.

For example:

```
byte** map(const char c)
{
    return numbers[c-'0'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide an index to skip some array members, like this:

```
byte numbersAndLetters[][6][4]={
  {ZERO},
  {ONE},
  {TWO},
  {THREE},
  {FOUR},
  {FIVE},
  {SIX},
  {SEVEN},
  {EIGHT},
  {NINE},
['A'] = {LETTER_A}, // Instead of hardcoding 65, use 'A'
  {LETTER_B}
  ...
};
```

This form of initializer lets you skip some elements, leaving them default-initialized.

Note: it is generally not a good idea to use `#define` for items that can be used only as part of a larger syntactic structure. For example, the ten digits that you define cannot be used outside of an array initializer, and they need curly braces around them. You should define them inline, and add comments for clarity:

```
byte numbers[][6][4]={
  {{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}}, // Zero
  {{0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,1}}, // One
  ..
}
```

Comment: The 10 should be 92 if you want to add A..Z

Comment: @cup You're right - I should omit the first index altogether, because the compiler is much better at counting than me.

Comment: Maybe better use comments at the start of the line, like /*Zero*/, to put the readable info where it will be read first.

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight. This is the way it actually was before I added the #define. I added the #define just because of the readability. I need to work it out now and see which solution fits better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.  (This is a common bad solution to your request.)

You may come accross some references that suggest that you can do something like

```
    int  a[10]={5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
    int *pA=a-5;
```

And that now `pA[5]` would reference the first element of the array.

Don't do this.

The standard allows for implementations where generation of pA would create a trap due to creating an invalid pointer.    Pointers are not required to be valid outside the object
pointed to or one element off the end of that object.

In many cases this type of code will work, but it is not required to so.  It should be avoided.

Reference C99 6.5.6 additive operators in regards to additive operations where one of the operands of the addition is a pointer:  "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow, otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NUL  {{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}}
#define ZERO {{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}}
#define ONE {{0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,1}}
#define TWO {{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,1,1,1}}
#define THREE {{1,1,1,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,1}}
#define FOUR {{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,1},{0,1,0,1},{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1}}
#define FIVE {{1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0},{1,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}}
#define SIX {{0,0,1,1},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}}
#define SEVEN {{1,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0}}
#define EIGHT {{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0}}
#define NINE {{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,1},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0}}
#define __A  {{0,1,1,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,1}}
/* ...finish out the entire character set if you wish */

byte numbers[256][6][4]=
  {
  NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, //0-15
  NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, //16-31
  NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, NUL, //32-47
  ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, //48-63
  __A, __B, __C, __D, __E, __F, __G, __H, __I, __J, __K, __L, __M, __N, __O, //64-79
  /* ...finish out the entire character set if you wish */
  };
```